# Authenticate google user without manual login for running google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I have written an API that calls my Google App script which basically uploads a file to Google Drive using the file URl that is passed by my API.But whenever I call the Google App Script it redirects to  login page. I want to login into the Google Drive account without login page. Can I do this with any auth service?
Since I will be personally using the script I have no problem in hard coding user login credentials also.

Scenario:

1.My php API passes a URL to Google App Script that I have uploaded as a web app.

2.Google app script redirects to login page.

Following is my Google App Script Code:

```
function doGet(e) {
var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(e.parameters.url).getBlob();
var id = DriveApp.createFile(blob).getId();
return ContentService.createTextOutput("Your file has been successfully 
uploaded");
}
```

Comment: You can use any number of the auth services. Review the Google Cloud Identity page, pick one, try to implement it, and ask about specific issues in your implementation.

Comment: @tehhowch I am running the API locally to hit my google script.How do I authenticate a user for google drive?

Comment: Review the PHP quickstart. This should be covered there.

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? Using Web Apps, you want to make users upload files to your Google Drive? Or you want to make users upload files to each user's Google Drive? If it's the former, users can upload files without each authorization, because the authorization has already done when Web Apps is deployed. If it's the latter, each user has to authorize when they use Web Apps, because users are required to authorize the scopes of Web Apps.

Comment: @Tanaike I want to upload file to a particular user's account that I decide.Example - Say I want it to upload to user X account. When I call my custom API it should call my Google  app script and upload it to the user X account.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If the user X deploys Web Apps as ``"Execute the app as:" : Me`` and ``"Who has access to the app:": Anyone, even anonymous``, other users can use Web Apps without the authorization, because Web Apps is deployed as the user X. When Web Apps is deployed as except for above settings, users are required to authorize to access to the Web Apps. Although I'm not sure whether this is useful for your situation, how about the information like [this](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks.Your detailed documentation about web apps solved my issue.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tanaike mentioned  you need to deploy your Web Apps as "Execute the app as:" : Me and "Who has access to the app:": Anyone, even anonymous, other users can use Web Apps without the authorization.